# Can you broadcast an external web page on Browsersync or does it have to be a site from within your own codebase?

Tags: browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

I think I have a basic misunderstanding of how Browsersync works. Forgive my question. I have read the documentation and the issues on GitHub and here.

I do understand that it works on two levels:

The first level is when you change your code it automatically synchs the changes on all of the devices.

The second level is you perform a user action on one browser - then on the external IP Address it displays/broadcasts to all other devices on the same IP address.

I'm asking in regard to the second scenario - can you broadcast by proxy a site where you don't own the codebase?

1. I Have a simple HTML/JS/CSS example website integrated with Browsersync.
2. I created this as a concept to see if others could see the actions I was taking from my desktop.
3. The proof of concept works fine. Other people within my network using my Browsersync IP Address can see my actions as I make them.
4. Can you broadcast/proxy a site that you don't own and is not part of your codebase?

   For example, if I wanted to broadcast [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com) so other people within my network could see the actions I was taking on my local Browsersync URL?

   (We do have our own development site https: //somenewsite.com so I really just want to broadcast that site not a true outside site).
5. Or can I only use Browsersync to broadcast a page from within my own codebase?

I tried using the proxy attribute but I'm not sure it does what I think it does.